# Readd a deleted node to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm implementing a function which can make a node offline/online from kubernetes cluster.

When I run `kubectl delete node $nodename`, how can I read this node to the cluster?

It's said that if use API `POST /api/v1/nodes` will cause the node state `Not ready`. Is there a way to read the deleted node to cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to (re)create a node depends on your cluster setup and Kubernetes version.

- [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#joining-your-nodes): run `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm join ...` again on the node (you might need to create a new token if the original one was short-lived, see the linked doc)
- most clouds: delete the VM. It will be recreated and will rejoin the cluster
- others: see [self registration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#self-registration-of-nodes) and [manual registration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration) for details.

Answer (score 2):

To add a previously deleted node on kubernetes > 1.8x for me it works restarting kubelet service on the node. It is registering then again in the cluster.
But kubernetes has a possibility to make a node "online/offlilne":

```
> kubectl cordon -h 
Mark node as unschedulable.

Examples:
  # Mark node "foo" as unschedulable.
  kubectl cordon foo

Usage:
  kubectl cordon NODE [options]
```

and

```
> kubectl uncordon -h 
Mark node as schedulable.

Examples:
  # Mark node "foo" as schedulable.
  $ kubectl uncordon foo

Usage:
  kubectl uncordon NODE [options]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seams that kubectl delete node only delete resource yaml file.

### So for me worked out:

```
kubectl apply -f node.yaml
```

--- node.yaml ---

```
{
  "kind": "Node",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "minion-0",
    "labels": {
      "name": "fixed"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By Mistakenly I have deleted the node running on mY Linux PC.

When I ran the command `kubectl get node` it returns a message "No resource found".

To give a try to solve this, I went to path /etc/systemd/system and ran `sudo systemctl restart k3s.service` and I see the deleted node gets re-added.

Thankfully I saved my time :) I hope it will be helpful for someone